# Zend Paginator Filter results

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I have a results set using Zend Paginator, its all working fine but I need to filter the results by using checkbox options like on eBay, Amazon etc..

I have read about Zend filter but dont know where to start.

Do anyone have any experience of this please?

Thanks

John

Comment: Can you post part of your code here?

Comment: What adapter do you use for your paginator?

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Filter is to transform something into something, like a translator.

The huge advantage of Zend_Paginator is that it retrieves data page by page. Figure out you want to display 30 items from a several millions table. It would be a very slow process if you retrieve all data and then filter accordingly to take out those 30 items.

Supposing you are retrieving your items from the database, your should use a `DbSelect` or `DbTableSelect` adaptor. Use `DbTableSelect` if you retrieve from one table and `DbSelect` if you retrieve from more than one table by joining.

Once you have your `$select` object with which you would retrieve all items in all pages, the paginator will retrieve the items page by page by setting a limit and offset. For instance, if you are displaying 30 items per page and you want to display the page number 3, the paginator will set `$select->limit(30, 60)` (you don't need to do this, the paginator does it for you). To accomplish this, try following in your controller:

```
// pass ?page=N in the url
$pageNumber = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page', 1);
// itemsPerPage can also be read from the url
$itemsPerPage = 30;
// this $select must retrieve all items in all pages
$select = new Zend_Db_Select();
$select->from(...)
    // eventually joins, where, or order statements
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($select);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($pageNumber);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($itemsPerPage);
```

You finally need to pass the paginator to the template is rendering the items and the pagination control. So add

```
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

and edit the template as in http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.rendering

So it's the basic functionality of the paginator. I hope this helps. It would be very similar if you are using other type of adapters like `Array` or `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox options have nothing to do with Zend_Paginator.

Zend_Paginator is just a Helper class that helps you paginate your results, it adds LIMIT clause and make templating the results easier, nothing more.

What you're lookig for is called '[Faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search)', you have to develop the logic behind it or use a search engine like Solr that can generate it automatically